# Troubles populating a gridview

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I'm having a problem populating a datagridview with data from ms- access. I have two tables, Rate and Play. Play is a foreign key of Rate. So, when I try to populate the gridview I want to show the name of the Play that is a property of Play. I tried writing Rate.Play.Name, Play.Name, P.Name but I didn't have success. Does anybody know how can I solve this issue? I'm stuck here for 2 days

This is the query

SELECT * FROM ((TH_RATE T INNER JOIN TH_PLAY O ON O.IdPlay= T.IdPlay) INNER JOIN TH_SECTION Z ON Z.idSection= T.IdSection) INNER JOIN TH_THEATER TE ON TE.IdTheather = Z.IdTheater WHERE T.IdPlay= @idObra

In DataPropertyName I have to put the property of the object, for example Name,
but "Obra"(Play) is an object and a property of "Tarifa"(Rate). So I tried with a lot of options include Rate.Play.Name, Play.Name but I got nothing yet

By the way, sorry because my program is spanish, I'm from Peru

[image]

[image]

Comment: This needs some code examples and more context around the problem, plus what you have already tried.

Comment: I dont know how to show that because is a property of the gridview. DataPropertyNaMe

Comment: You are using terms which mean nothing and confuse people (Obra, Tarifa)

Comment: can you share your sql query

Comment: Sorry @benPearce I'm translating my code because it's in spanish

Comment: I'm still lost as to where the actual problem is. It would help if you could upload your datagrid code and small example of the data returned from the sql statement you've written. Based on the data and the datagrid and code, it could provide some insight

Comment: @AlexW I added the images

Comment: You could try asking your question here: http://es.stackoverflow.com/